# How to display post permalinks instead of pages?

Tags: permalinks, urls

I am working on a website for comics, and whenever you go to it, it should open the latest POST. I have no pages, I deleted them all. All the website has, is posts.

So I want that whenever people start going "Next" to the next posts, it will display the permalinks (fancy URL) of posts, not weird page URL such as:

```
www.example.com/?p24
```

Comment: In `/wp-admin` &raquo; **Settings** &raquo; **Permalinks**, choose "Post Name" permalink and save. Isn't that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your permalinks? If so, you shouldn't have this issue. If not, just go to Settings --> Permalinks and change them to suit your needs, for example using Custom Structure and then `/%category%/%postname%/`